# wsl on Windows 10 not loading config files when ran interoperabiltiy

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have read the [Microsoft Docs for WSL Interop mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop), but when I run `wsl "env"` it doesn't seem to be loading any of the `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, or `.bashrc`. However, obviously when I run the application by just saying `wsl` it starts up an interative, login bash session or whatever my default shell is.

How does the `wsl` command load the bash configs and why aren't they being loaded when running in "interop" mode?

I am trying to run `wsl nvim`, but I get `/bin/bash: nvim: command not found` and when I just run `wsl.exe`, I can run nvim with no issues.